# import multiple svgs in one xml with d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

currently I'm fiddling with D3.js. It looks awesome!I was wondering if D3.js is suitable to draw multiple svg elements in a webpage. I found the d3.xml method and got it working.

Initially I was playing with Raphaeljs but, for me as a JS-newbie, useful tuts/docs are hard to find. I was converting SVG's to JSON-objects with webtool and then inculde them in 1 js-file it's a lot of work stripping tags and stuff. This saves HTTP-requests. Now I want to try the same with D3.js and see which one will suit me.

Any ideas for importing a multiple-SVG-file with D3?

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit number of SVGs you can write using D3.  All D3 does is access the DOM and modify it so that the browser knows to draw an SVG, or how to manipulate the SVG.  D3 simply allows you to more easily access the elements and work with them.

If you are reading the SVGs from JSON objects, you just need to read in the multiple JSONS.

Take the first two examples from the D3js.org website as an example...

```
d3.csv("morley.csv", function(error, csv) {
  var data = [];

  csv.forEach(function(x) {
    var e = Math.floor(x.Expt - 1),
        r = Math.floor(x.Run - 1),
        s = Math.floor(x.Speed),
        d = data[e];
    if (!d) d = data[e] = [s];
    else d.push(s);
    if (s > max) max = s;
    if (s < min) min = s;
  });

  chart.domain([min, max]);

  var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("class", "box")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(chart);

  d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
    svg.datum(randomize).call(chart.duration(1000)); // TODO automatic transitions
  });
});
```

This, from the Box Plot example, will open up "morley.csv" and work with the data.

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});
```

This, from the Bubble Chart example, will open up "flare.json" and start doing stuff with that.  There is nothing stopping you from doing both of these actions in the same file.

What you will have to look out for is variable references, as with any other program.  Each SVG will need its own reference.  The above two code blocks use the same variable names for several things, so they'd step on each other.  If you wanted both these on one page, you would simply need to rename the variables so they are unique.

Comment: Thanx for your really thourough answer. I'll dig into it!!! It's a bit complex for me but have start somewhere don't I?!

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.xml("./svgs.xml", "application/xml", function(xml, error) {

    var data = xml.documentElement,
        sections = data.getElementsByTagName("section"),
        svgWrapper = "center";


    for (var i = 0, lenS = sections.length; i < lenS; i++) {    

        var name = sections[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
            images = sections[i].getElementsByTagName("image");

        for (var j = 0, lenI = images.length; j < lenI ; j++) {   

            //<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
            var image = images[j].firstElementChild;

            //assuming I only target 1 unique HTML5-element
            if (document.getElementsByTagName(name)[0] !== undefined) {

                //in search of wrapper-class and append data to it
                document.getElementsByTagName(name)[0].getElementsByClassName(svgWrapper)[0].appendChild(image);

            // If node "name" is not a element then it's an id
            } else if (document.getElementById(name) !== undefined) {

                document.getElementById(name).getElementsByClassName(svgWrapper)[0].appendChild(image);
            } else {

                console.alert("what the hell went wrong while inserting svgs?!");
                alert("What the hell went wrong while inserting svgs?!");
            }

        }   
    }
});
```

If somebody got pointers to maybe improve this for like IE9 cause only test this for Chrome and Firefox (have to install Windows VM). How do I catch and handle the error-parameter in the XHR?